# Чтение числа из формы и вывод записи с соответствующим номером из базы MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Итак: есть таблица в MySQL, в ней у каждой записи свой идентификатор. На веб-странице - форма:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="number" placeholder="№ предмета" name="item-number"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="think" value="Подумать">
</form>
```

Нужен скрипт, который проверял бы, есть ли в таблице запись с таким номером, и если есть, на новой странице выводил бы всю эту запись.

Comment: Покажите Вашу реализацию задачи, вставьте в вопрос код, с которым у Вас возникли проблемы. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

У вас 3 варианта: написать такой скрипт самой, заказать написание скрипта фрилансеру, либо уговорить кого-нибудь написать его бесплатно.

Если решитесь написать самостоятельно, то вместо постановки задачи (или вместе с ней) спрашивайте конкретные вопросы. Тогда есть шанс, что Вам помогут решить конкретную проблему